# Getting data from PHP to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send some data from PHP back to AJAX. I found some examples but it doesn't seem to work. The result of console log is: "test: success". How can I get the data?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "assets/psv.php",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "HTML",
    success: function(results, test){
        console.log("test:" + test);
    },
    error : function (e) {
        console.log("error " + e);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
$test= "pgv";

echo $test;
```

Comment: Could you share a link or a fiddle? And please update the PHP code with the suggestions..

Comment: Why did you choose the other answer? If you hadn't added the _json_encode_ it would never have worked...

Comment: the other answer works with json_encode

Comment: Yes but I got the solution.

Comment: I think @Tony is right.

Comment: Thanks @MarkYisri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first variable in the success callback contains data received from the page you called.

**PHP**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$test= "pgv";

echo json_encode($test);
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "assets/psv.php",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response, status){
        console.log("test", response.data); //CHANGE THIS!!
    },
    error : function (e) {
        console.log("error " + e);
    }
});
```

data will contain

```
{
    headers: "...",
    data: "pgv",
    ....
}
```

Comment: I get test: undefined

Comment: dataType: "json", also since you're posting nothing, you could set "GET", instead of "POST"

Comment: also did you set header('Content-Type: application/json'); in your PHP?

Comment: with json_encode I get again test: undefined. Maybe the problem is that the AJAX function is inside another ajax function success?

Comment: try to log all _response_ now that you have the _json_encode_

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "assets/psv.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        console.log("test:" + data);
    },
    error : function (e) {
        console.log("error " + e);
    }
});
```

or something like this:

```
$.get( "assets/psv.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Comment: I still get test:success

Comment: try removing your data type `dataType: "HTML"`

Comment: @GoGo make sure that you've cleared your browser cache, this answer is totally right